# Domain Mapping with php?

Tags: php, dns, domain-mapping

today im playing with domains with php,

example

```
www.wordpress.com is our main site
www.friend1.com is my new domain
www.friend2.com is my new domain
www.friend3.com is my new domain
```

to

```
www.friend1.com the same as www.wordpress.com/profile/friend1 ?
www.friend2.com the same as www.wordpress.com/profile/friend3 ?
www.friend3.com the same as www.wordpress.com/profile/friend2 ?
```

**how do wordpress, etc do things like that? are they doing that in the server side ? 
or there is a way doing stuff like that in php?**

*edit
if you still dont get it,

heres a example. lets say you have a friend deviantart id at myfrienddeviantartid.devaintart.com and lets say you are the admin on deviantart. you want to make a addon service that your friend can park his own domain into deviantart.com.

Answer (score 0):

This is traditionally done using mod_rewrite inside Apache's configuration. It remaps URLs.

Comment: yup, i was thinking that too, but i just cant think how would they manage a lot of domain by useing mod_rewrite via apache.

Comment: Well, the rules are configured using perl-compatible regular expressions so you don't have to define every possible URL scenario. For example, to grab 'friend3' out of "www.friend3.com" you can use the regular expression "\.(\w)\." and place the matched result into your new, rewritten url. The regex is probably more complex than that and you'd have to test it obviously; but you get the idea.

Comment: nope, i was thinking using a database, first i see where he goes from, if the domain is on domains.url1.com ( ns config is right ) we just have to redirect the www.url2.com see to www.url1.com/destination with $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] then if not the same as domains.url1.com it will redirect to a proper url in the field ( fetched from database )

Comment: is it bad ? or maybe we should append the .htacsess, but i dont feel its a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

- For apache http server, it uses **ProxyPassReverse** directive from mod_proxy or directives from mod_rewrite

> The directive  ProxyPassReverse lets Apache adjust the URL in the
>   Location header on HTTP redirect responses. For instance this is
>   essential when Apache is used as a reverse proxy to avoid by-passing
>   the reverse proxy because of HTTP redirects on the backend servers
>   which stay behind the reverse proxy.
>
> Suppose the local server has address http://wibble.org/; then
>
> ProxyPass /mirror/foo/ http://foo.com/
>   ProxyPassReverse  /mirror/foo/ http://foo.com/
>
> will not only cause a local request for the
>   http://wibble.org/mirror/foo/bar to be internally converted into a
>   proxy request to http://foo.com/bar (the functionality ProxyPass
>   provides here). It also takes care of redirects the server foo.com
>   sends: when http://foo.com/bar is redirected by him to
>   http://foo.com/quux Apache adjusts this to
>   http://wibble.org/mirror/foo/quux before forwarding the HTTP redirect
>   response to the client.

- For MS(R) IIS use **Re-Write** Module:

> Easily replace Web application URLs to produce user and search engine >friendly results.
>   URL Rewrite permits Web administrators to easily replace the URLs >generated by a Web application in the response HTML with a more user friendly and search engine friendly equivalent. Links can be modified in the HTML markup generated by a Web application behind a reverse proxy. URL Rewrite makes things easier for outbound response content and headers rewriting with outbound rewrite rules that work with HTTP request and response headers and with IIS server variables.

Additionaly, you must make sure that subdomain is setup with DNS provider to pass **all** requests to main.

DNS Record Sample:

```
NAME                    TYPE   VALUE
--------------------------------------------------
exampleXYZ.com.         CNAME  example.com.
example.com.            A      192.0.2.23
```

Ref:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record
2. http://www.akadia.com/services/apache_redirect.html
3. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html
4. http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite